# Finding similar words using word2vec and gensim, throwing error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gensim, word2vec, drive

I am trying to find words similar to a word I give the code. But somehow everything goes fine till the end, where it says the word doesn't exist. Could someone help me?

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec

glove_file = datapath('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/glove.6B.300d.txt')
tmp_file = get_tmpfile('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/word2vec-glove.6B.300d.txt')

_ = glove2word2vec(glove_file, tmp_file)

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(tmp_file)

model.most_similar(positive=["new"], topn=10)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0752cfe838d7> in <module>()
     10 model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(tmp_file)
     11 
---> 12 model.most_similar(positive=["new"], topn=10)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in word_vec(self, word, use_norm)
    450             return result
    451         else:
--> 452             raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
    453 
    454     def get_vector(self, word):

KeyError: "word 'new' not in vocabulary"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're receiving an error, `KeyError: "word 'new' not in vocabulary"`, then the word `'new'` is probably not in the model's vocabulary – even if you expected/intended it to be.

Have you examined the source GLoVe file, `/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/glove.6B.300d.txt`, to confirm it has the expected length/content?

Have you examined the output text word2vec-format file, `/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/word2vec-glove.6B.300d.txt`?

Have you checked that the `model`, once loaded, has the expected count of words inside (`len(model)`), or that its 1st few words (`model.index_to_key[20]`) look correct?

These checks will probably show some more foundational problem than the `KeyError` during `most_similar()` you're hitting - so repeating the GLoVe vector download/conversion/load & ensuring each step succeeded without errors may resolve the problem.

Note also:

The `glove2word2vec()` function/script is now deprecated, as of Gensim version 4.0 (2021). If you use it, you should be seeing a warning message:

> KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(.., binary=False, no_header=True)
> loads GLoVE text vectors.

So you can skip the explicit conversion, and just use that instead:

```
glove_vecs = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(glove_file, binary=False, no_header=True)
```

(This read will require one extra initial pass, to count the number of included words, so if you'll be repeating this load a lot, you might still want to re-save the `glove_vecs` to a new separate file, with `.save_word2vec_format()`, if load-speed is a concern.)